# Sorting and auto filtering Excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to sort a spreadsheet using openpyxl and Python. I have read the documents and I don't quite understand this page. I am expecting it to either add the auto filter dropdown arrows or sort my spreadsheet and it is returning errors. Here's my code

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('report.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws['A2'] = "Store"
ws['B2'] = "Manager"
ws['C2'] = "Zone"
ws.column_dimensions.group('F','DU',hidden=True)
#ws.AutoFilter.add_sort_condition('C:C')
wb.save("report.xlsx")
```

According to the documents it looks like the line "ws.AutoFilter.add_sort_condition('C:C')" should give me the result I want. (Yes I understand it is currently a comment line. The rest of my code runs fine without that line so I commented it.)

When I have that line in the code I get the error - 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'AutoFilter' but according to the documents it looks like it does. http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/filters.html#AutoFilter.

If anyone can help explain to me why it is failing or what the documents mean that would be great.

This statement in the documents is particularly confusing to me:

> "Don't create auto filters by yourself. It is created by :class:`~openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet`.
>       You can use via :attr:`~~openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.auto_filter` attribute."

because I tried that too and it also failed.

Update: @crussell's reply worked in that it added the auto filter to my spreadsheet. However, it is still not adding the sort condition to the appropriate column.

Comment: It looks like you need `ws.auto_filter.add_sort_condition('C:C')`

Comment: @MorganThrapp Thanks for the suggestion! I was able to successfully run the code without any errors using your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't sort anything in any way whatsoever.

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation openpyxl can define the filter and/or sort but does not apply them!

They can only be applied from within Excel

Answer (score 5):

See here: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html?highlight=auto_filter#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.auto_filter

The auto_filter command returns the AutoFilter object, so in a sense they are the same thing.

What you need is `ws.auto_filter.ref = 'C1:C20'`
with the range of cells those of which you want to filter.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a full answer for this, but I did find something interesting when using filters. 
I added a filter column, 
eg:
  `ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(1,{},True)`

then I opened the resulting spreadsheet. The column showed the filter! But the data was not actually filtered in the spreadsheet. I had to click on the "Data" tab and click "Reapply" the filter.

So it looks like the adding of a sort or filter column works, except it never actually applies the sort or filter.

I have been hunting down a function that will apply the filter, but have not yet had any luck. If anyone has thoughts, I'd love to hear them!

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like hidden columns for filters are not yet supported...
[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/Qln2gZbuY1c)

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the documentation and the source code for the AutoFilter.add_sort_condition() function it looks like the ref you're providing may need to be changed to include row indices, like "C1:C120", for example. Have you tried it with specific row numbers? Also, be sure to take a look at the comment regarding the ref variable right below the function declaration in:

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/filters.html#AutoFilter

if you're not following where I'm coming from. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: I tried running the code with row indices but it unfortunately still didn't sort or even add the auto filter to my spreadsheet. Thanks for the help. Also could anyone help me understand, according to the docs for openpyxl the difference and the difference in syntax between AutoFilter and auto_filter. The documentation doesn't seem very clear but I could just be misunderstanding it. Thanks again!