# openpyxl can set the filter but can't apply them

Tags: filter, openpyxl

In [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614890/sorting-and-auto-filtering-excel-with-openpyxl) many says things that "openpyxl can define the filter and/or sort but does not apply them".

This is exactly what I see in my experiment. I am doing this by code

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

targetFile = "test.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(targetFile)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(1, ['A'], None)
wb.save(targetFile)
```

After I open the excel, I do see the checkbox of 'A' get selected, but the filter is not working until I apply the filter in the GUI.

[image]

Is this a permanent limitation of openpyxl? Any alternative to apply the filter inside the python script?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html?highlight=filter#using-filters-and-sorts). Specifically **Note: Filters and sorts can only be configured by openpyxl but will need to be applied in applications like Excel. This is because they actually rearrange, format and hide rows in the range.** As it states the application of the filter is by Excel so Openpyxl cannot do that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the official doc, is it possible this limitation might be fixed in future version of openpyxl, or it is its design philosophy that openpyxl won't touch excel application level operations so this limitation will be permanent?

Comment: Openpyxl modifies the xml files that make up an xlsx file. Operations that Excel does as an application cannot be achieved so there are a few things that Openpyxl can never do for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to run Xlwings, since that module does run Excel you can use it to set and apply your filter;

```
import xlwings as xw

file = 'test.xlsx'
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(file)
    ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

    ws.used_range.api.AutoFilter(Field := 3, Criteria1 := "A")
    ws.show_autofilter = True

    wb.save("out_test.xlsx")
```

[xlwings](/questions/tagged/xlwings)

Comment: My filter is in `C2` cell, how should I set the `Field`?

Comment: The code example as shown should do what you want as it takes the used range A1:C5 and applies the filter, then on the the 3rd field Grade applies the criteria 'A'.

Comment: Find that if I need multiple selector, need to add `operator := 7`, very strange syntax but it works! Thank you @moken

Comment: One side effect is that I find after 'xlwings` filter operation and save, the excel size becomes 10 times larger than original.

Comment: Do some further investigation, I unzip the xlsx and investigate on individual worksheet.xml. Before the filter, it has `<dimension ref="A1:G139"/>`. After the filter it has `<dimension ref="A1:G100001"/>`. Many many lines added

Comment: Was the Excel file originally created by Openpyxl? If so this is normal. An xlsx file created by Openpyxl does not contain all the xml files that a file created by Excel has. Therefore if you create the file in Openpyxl then open it in Excel (or another module using Excel like Xlwings ) and save, Excel will add the additonal files and maybe add to some of the existing xmls as well. So even if nothing has been added to the file by the code it will be larger, though 10 times larger seems excessive.

Comment: Turn out it is not relevant to xlwings. If I manually select the items in filters, the file size will also increase. Smells like the `autoFilter` applies to range up to column 100001 and increase the individual sheet size

Comment: The root cause is this: a worksheet has max_row = 100, however its autofilter has range "A1:G100001". After apply the filter, the row actually grows. I fix this by first using `openpyxl` to set `ws.auto_filter.ref` from "A1:G100001" to "A1:G100". Then use `xlwings` to apply the filter. The result excel is not growing size any more

Comment: I was never able to duplicate the issue, with a sheet of around 100 rows and 7 columns the original and saved sizes were the same. Did you try specifying the actual range rather than using `used_range` in Xlwings, something like `ws.api.Range("$A$1:$C$100").AutoFilter(Field := 3, Criteria1 := "A", operator := 7)`